# Rails ActiveRecord how to do custom sorting on a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Lets say I have two Models a Business and a TimeSlot, and the relationship is that `business has_many :timeslots`. each time slot has a day column which stores the dayname like `'Monday', 'Tuesday'` etc.

When I do

```
bussiness.time_slots
```

I get timeslots that are not sorted. I want the timeslots to be sorted by daynames (not alphabatically). times slots with 'Monday' come first than 'Tuesday' and so on.

I think SQL can't help me with this because the sorting is custom, I will need to sort after I read, but I am concerned about where to put which code

I can do something like

in my controller

```
b = current_business
TimeSlot.find_sorted_with_busines(b)
```

in my TimeSlot Model

```
def find_sorted_with_business(b)
   b.time_slots
   # sort timeslots using custom sorting here and return
end
```

but I dont like the idea of passing a business object or id to the TimeSlot model, I should be able to do something like

```
b = current_business
b.sorted_timeslots
```

how can I do this ?

Ideas on how to do custom sorting based on daynames are also welcome :)

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered storing integers instead of the day names. Would make it easier to sort. And you could override the getter and setter to go from day names to integer or the opposite. Just a thought.

Comment: never thought of that.. looks like a nice idea and I think it would help remove a lot of mess. I am going to try it

Comment: @Robin if you move this to an answer I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider storing integers in the database instead of the day names. It would make things easier to sort, and probably a bit more performant.

Then, you can override the `day` getter (to return the day name from the integer) and setter (to store the integer corresponding to the day name). You might not have to override the setter depending on what you get from your form.

Don't forget to have a custom validation, to check if the integer is between 1 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

you CAN do custom sorting with sql:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN dayname = 'Monday' THEN 1
        WHEN dayname = 'Tuesday' THEN 2
        .
        .
        WHEN dayname = 'Sunday' THEN 7
        ELSE 8
     END
```

but the best is to use just an int for the column type like robin suggested and then use the number to get the day name and the order will simpler